# PowerShell ProtectedData.Unprotect Fails in Console but Works in ISE

Tags: powershell, encryption, cryptography, system.security

Im trying to encrypt and decrypt passwords, i've made 2 functions:

```
function VA-EncryptPassword {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$PlainPassword
    )

    # Add assembly for security
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Security"

    # Convert password string to a byte array
    $PlainPasswordBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($PlainPassword)

    # Encrypt the password (machine-specific)
    $EncryptedPassword = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect($PlainPasswordBytes, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::LocalMachine)

    # Optionally, convert the byte array to Base64 for easier storage or transmission
    $Encrypted64Password = [Convert]::ToBase64String($EncryptedPassword)

    # Return the Base64 encrypted password
    $Encrypted64Password
}

function VA-DecryptPassword {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Encrypted64Password
    )

    # Add assembly for security
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Text.Encoding

    # Convert the Base64 encrypted password back to a byte array
    $EncryptedPasswordBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($Encrypted64Password)

    # Decrypt the password using DPAPI
    $DecryptedPasswordBytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($EncryptedPasswordBytes, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::LocalMachine)

    # Convert byte array back to a string
    $DecryptedPassword = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($DecryptedPasswordBytes)

    # Return the decrypted password
    $DecryptedPassword
}
```

I get: exception calling "unprotect" with "3" arguments: "The operation completed successfully"
Which means, it runs it but the result is null (?)

It functions correctly on several servers, except 2.
The tricky part is, if i run the script in the Powershell ISE, i can do both encrypt and decrypt.
However, i can't decrypt do it with neither Console nor' Scheduled Task.

I can encrypt with the console, and decrypt with the ISE. But i can't for the life of me decrypt with console.

I've checked everything i could think of, Env:, $Profile, Features on the serves that work vs. the ones that doesn't, try as admin, regular user, checked .Net Framework and Core versions, and they both run powershell 5.xx (identical)

I hope someone has a bright idea, or has run into the issue themselves.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you could simply use the PowerShell [`ConvertFrom/To-SecureString` cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring), a [Data Protection API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) encrypted string can only be decrypted under the same computer/user account as where it is created. This is by (security) design.

Comment: The convertFrom/To is not useable for us, as that IS locked to the User as well.
And it is, to my knowledge locked to the same Computer, not user when using the cryptography But it simply doesn't work either way, even with the same user in Console and Ise.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell (not ISE) are you using? Windows PowerShell or PowerShell 7.x?

Comment: Powershell 5.xx, identical on the server working and the one NOT working.